# How do you get a Bootstrap 5.2 Popover to fire in an "if" statement?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, popover

I am using popovers as part of an input validation process. I have the idea but I can't work out the syntax on how to get this to work.

https://jsbin.com/sufitelodo/1/edit?html,js,output

This JSBin is the basis of it.

I don't know how to write the HTML for a hidden Bootstrap 5.2 popover that comes up only when called in an `if` statement. To run this, type the number 0 into input A and any number into input B and the same number again into input C. The first error should be that input A = 0 and then you change that to any non-zero and then the second error should happen when you try and submit. I would like to change from the alert boxes to popovers.

```js
const popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
);
const popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, { html: true });
});



document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", testMe);

function testMe() {
  let inputA = parseFloat(document.getElementById("aInput").value);
  let inputB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bInput").value);
  let inputC = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cInput").value);
  let popoverTest1 = document.getElementById("popoverTest1");
  let popoverTest2 = document.getElementById("popoverTest2");
  
  if (inputA === 0) {
    // Make popoverTest1 come up here
    //alert("This is when popoverTest1 should fire");
    bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest1').show()
    
    return false;
    
  } else if (inputB === inputC) {
    // Make popoverTest2 come up here
    //alert("This is when popoverTest2 should fire");
    bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest2').show()
    
    return false;
  }
}

document.getElementById("close1").addEventListener("click", closePop);
function closePop () {
  bootstrap.Popover.getInstance('#popoverTest1').hide();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label for="aInput">A Input</label>
  <input type="number" id="aInput">
  <span id="popoverTest1" 
          data-bs-container="body" 
          data-bs-toggle="popover" 
          data-bs-trigger="manual" 
          data-bs-content="Top popover"
          data-bs-title='This is zero <a href="" id="close1">x</a>'
          data-bs-content='Change it to something non-zero'>
</span>
  <br><br>
  <label for="bInput">B Input</label>
  <input type="number" id="bInput">
  <span id="popoverTest2" 
          data-bs-container="body" 
          data-bs-toggle="popover" 
          data-bs-trigger="manual" 
          data-bs-content="Top popover"
          data-bs-title="This is the same as Input C"
          data-bs-content="Change it so it's not the same as Input C">
</span>
  <br> <br>
  <label for="cInput">C Input</label>
  <input type="number" id="cInput">
 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="button">Hit Me</button>
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So, instead of the alerts I would like a cleaner popover from Bootstrap, but the syntax and getting them to work (even after trying to decipher the documentation) isn't on my side. Then after the popover is opened it needs to be able to be closed again.

I tried `data-bs-trigger="focus"` but this does not seem to have enabled closing.

Thanks kindly for your help on this.

*** Edit - I have updated the code to allow for just using Vanilla but there is an error with using the close button... I can't seem to dispose of the popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included all the required assets as described in the documentation here (for the version 5.2):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

And used the exact code snippet showed here to initialize all the popovers:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/

The strategy to get the instance of a popover given a css selector:

```
const popover1 = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest1');
```

The methods you are interested to call when showing and hiding respectively are:

```
popover1.show();
popover1.hide();
```

The only action I added to your logic was hiding all popovers when clicking the button before showing the new one if that's the case.

Then I also added the strategy to deal with the click that will hide any visible popover in case there is any showing. Bootstrap relied on the attribute `data-bs-trigger` set as `focus` instead of `manual` but that implies the popover to be triggered through user interaction instead of a ***manual*** explicit call to the `.show()` method. So since we are showing the popovers via `.show()` we are doomed to implement the `.hide()` part also, that in this case is dealt by the click event handler on the window object.

```js
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", testMe);

window.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{    
    const popoverTest1 = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest1');
    const popoverTest2 = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest2');
    popoverTest1.hide();
    popoverTest2.hide();  
});

function testMe(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

  const inputA = parseFloat(document.getElementById("aInput").value);
  const inputB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bInput").value);
  const inputC = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cInput").value);
    
  const popoverTest1 = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest1');
  const popoverTest2 = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest2');

  popoverTest1.hide();
  popoverTest2.hide();

  if (inputA === 0) {    
    popoverTest1.show();
  } else if (inputB === inputC) {    
    popoverTest2.show();
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">      
  </head>
  <body>

    <label for="aInput">A Input</label>
    <input type="number" id="aInput">

    <!-- popoverTest1 -->
    <span      
      id="popoverTest1"
      data-bs-container="body"
      data-bs-toggle="popover"      
      data-bs-trigger="manual"      
      data-bs-title="This is zero"
      data-bs-content="Change it to something non-zero"></span>

    <br><br>

    <label for="bInput">B Input</label>
    <input type="number" id="bInput">

    <!-- popoverTest2 -->

    <span
      id="popoverTest2"
      data-bs-container="body"
      data-bs-toggle="popover"      
      data-bs-trigger="manual"      
      data-bs-title="This is the same as Input C"
      data-bs-content="Change it so it's not the same as Input C"></span>

    <br><br>
    <label for="cInput">C Input</label>
    <input type="number" id="cInput">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="button">Hit Me</button>
    
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have something similar working as well, but I was trying to get out of using jQuery.

Comment: I had tried this earlier: popoverTest1.popover('show'); (using the same variables) but it didn't work.

Comment: the code I shared before was working to me but it wasn't perfectly respecting the versions used. I just updated the answer to include exactly what's required to work with bootstrap 5.2. As a side note, the popovers require the popper.js library that in this case it's included in bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: I am using the full bundle on my site and the JSBin, the only thing I am having trouble with is that the Popover doesn't close on the next click. I changed `data-bs-trigger="manual"` to `data-bs-trigger="focus"` but that hasn't worked.

Comment: that's probably because the popover is supposed to be something triggered by the user action.. that's why the attribute is called trigger and its value is supposed to be manual or focus (or something else). The logs to dismiss the popover relies on the fact that the first click triggered its appearence. Since that strategy cannot work using the `.show` approach, I implemented my `.hide` part of the story adding a listener for the click event on the window object.

Comment: *the logic to dismiss the popover relies... (correcting a type I made before) ...maybe this comment was too much.. anyway now the code is working as expected. I will only add that anyway the dismissable popover had further requirements like using anchor element and a tabindex so using `hide()` in this case was much more appropriate anyway

Comment: Thank you... I am going to work with his method, it seems like it will fulfil my needs. I appreciate your help here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249868/discussion-between-paul-davis-and-diego-d).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the instance of the appropriate Popover and show it..

```
function testMe() {
    let inputA = parseFloat(document.getElementById("aInput").value);
    let inputB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bInput").value);
    let inputC = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cInput").value);
    let popoverTest1 = document.getElementById("popoverTest1");
    let popoverTest2 = document.getElementById("popoverTest2");
    if (inputA === 0) {
        // Make popoverTest1 come up here
        // alert("This is when popoverTest1 should fire");
        // document.getElementById("popoverTest1").popover('show')
        bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest1').show()
    }
    else if (inputB === inputC) {
        // Make popoverTest2 come up here
        //ert("This is when popoverTest2 should fire");
        bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popoverTest2').show()
    }
 }
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/dfGBtJO9yF)

Comment: oooooh... thank you. I tried that but not that syntax exactly. I am trying now.

Comment: Now it is just making it disappear again after.. but this is a magic help! Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any idea how you can make the popover clear on the next click? I tried changing `data-bs-trigger="manual"` to `data-bs-trigger="focus"` but this didn't work. Any clue?

Comment: It's a separate question. Please first accept this answer for the original question.